# QDR expressions in OLAP cube calculated measures

Tags: oracle, olap, dml

I'm becoming crazy with a calculated measure into OLAP Analytic Workspace Manager, that is defined like next OLAP Expression syntax:

> NVL(CUBE.MEASURE1[DIM1= 'A'], 0) + NVL(CUBE.MEASURE2[DIM2= 'B'], 0)

Where:
`CUBE.MEASURE1` and `CUBE.MEASURE2` are not calculated measures, they are stored measures.
**DIM1** and **DIM2** are edges of the **CUBE**, A and B values both exist in their dimensions.

In most of all my queries, the calculated measure retrieves correct results, when both members of the sum retrieves data. But I other cases the calculated measure retrieves null !!!

In these cases, the calculated measure retrieves null when `CUBE.MEASURE2[DIM2= 'B']` retrieves NO results. But I expect that if any of both QDR expresions retrieves no results, NVL function will replace it by 0.

I was reading about it, situations when QDR expressions retrieves no results, by default it throws and error and not null o NA value. I found that exist 2 ORACLE DML options that can manage this type of situations:

> LIMITSTRICT = NO

(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options043.htm#OLADM384)

> OKNULLSTATUS = YES

(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options077.htm#OLADM418)

I tried to create a DML Function in the AW to set both options, first to NO and second to YES, calling this function with OLAP_DML_EXPRESSION('MyFUNCTION', NUMBER) statement, but it doesn`t work

Please, I need a workaround of that, how I can catch these situations? Must I create a DML program to solve it? Where can I set this options (LIMITSTRICT,OKNULLSTATUS) by default and not set them in each measure calculation?